# Is this considered a O(log n) operation?

Tags: runtime, analysis

Let's say I'm traversing through an array and I'm only going to traverse it 1 time. Now say I have a loop iterating through this array which stops once it hits the last index. The loop is searching for the next value that *isn't* a 0. **The operation I am considering is the loop extracting the next non-zero value**.

For example my array could be:  | 1 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6 |

In this example my loop would retrieve 1 and do something with it. Then 7 and 6. Once an index is visited it isn't visited again.

So, would this be a O(log n) operation since the extraction of an element is never going to take n iterations?

Comment: What is `n`? Unless you can prove some additional guarantees about the array contents, your operation is `O(length_of_array)`.

Comment: n is the length of the array. Forgot to mention this but there is also no way for there to be all zeros. There will always be a non-zero number at index 0 and then another at least halfway through.

Comment: Which doesn't help you. n/2 is still O(n).

Comment: Why O(log n) specifically? In the context of arrays that would normally be associated with something like binary search.

Comment: Right, I was thinking it this sort of like a binary search where you never actually traverse through the entire array. Once you find an non-zero index you never look at it again. You keep track of where you left off.  So, I just keep thinking this won't be a O(n) operation and would instead need to be a O(log n).

Answer (score 0):

Big O is based on worst case scenarios, so we'd consider the case where your array looks like `| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |`.

In this case, it's O(n) because it would traverse each index once.

Comment: Forgot to mention this but there is also no way for there to be all zeros. There will always be a non-zero number at index 0 and then another at least halfway through.

Comment: I would consider that O(n/2), but that would simplify to O(n) still